# How to display custom fields on WordPress Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I have an online bookstore that is build from WordPress Woocommerce Plugin. But currently I am not able to add custom fields (author etc.) on a product.

How do i make it possible like the one on the photo below? Adding the Author of the books (highlighted in yellow).

[image]

This is the website : libroatbp2011.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on where you want to place it. The easiest way is to use the built in Product Attributes of WooCommerce.

[image]

This will display on the "Additional Information" tab on the product page.

[image]